# Meta viewport doesn't work for my website

Tags: html, css, viewport, meta

What I should do to this [page:](http://bit.ly/1vsxvXK)  to work right in mobile. I have tried meta viewport but It doesn't work. You can find the page [here:](http://bit.ly/1vsxvXK)

and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="english.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>

        <header class="mainHeader">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Magazine</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <section class="wr">
            <img src="images/right.png" class="right">
            <img src="images/left.png" class="left">
            <section class="wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1><a href="#" class="name">Photographer</a></h1>
                    <h1><a href="#" class="title">Story</a></h1>                    
                <p><a href="#" class="lead">DescriptionDescriptionDescription</a></p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
body{
    color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.9 );
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url("images/14thcover.jpg") ;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a:hover{
    color: black;
}
.mainHeader {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-right: 0.8em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;

}

.mainHeader a{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9)
}

.mainHeader a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7)
}
.wr {
    width: 75%;
    height:60%;
    min-height: 65%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 49%;
    right: 0;
}
.left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 49%;
    left: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height:auto;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.title {
    color: red;
}
.name, .lead {
    color: black;
}
.lead {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.container {
    width: auto;
    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    direction: rtl;
    font-weight: 80;
}
.container h1 {
    display: inline;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.container p {
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works as you have specified in your CSS. The problem is that these specific widths do not fit in smaller resolutions on the device screen without overlapping.
You must specify:

```
@media (max-with: 768px) {
     .mainHeader {
         float: none;
    }
}
```

You can reduce sizes and font sizes to still have the same look as in greater resolutions, but text become not readable or clickable

Comment: thanks Kikerrobles, I did what you wrote but I still have problem, the resuls is here:http://bit.ly/1A5CjX6

Comment: yes what you suggested is perfect but webmaster of this website wants the site still the same when it`s browsing in mobile. font-size should`nt become smaller when I consider it as em ?

Comment: It becomes smaller if you reduce the size of the container. Soy you have to reduce using @media the size of the container. But first you have to tell your client that he wants is nonsense and unusefull

Comment: And yes,in bit.ly/1A5CjX6 you have a plroblem too, you have to test in some widths your code and make changes in CSS so its still looking as you want. Theres no a magic way ;)

Comment: yes it`s nonsense :) I found a website to show you what exactly I mean , this website : http://bit.ly/1CUQkN7  is not fluid or responsive or addoptive but it shows the same without problem in mobile.

Comment: Dont use the meta viewport. So you will see the same as in your desktop browser, and use size in pixeles for containers, not percents and em

Comment: And if you still want to use percents insted fixed sizes, you have to specify at least that wr have the 75%, but header have to have the 25%, and you didn't do that.

Comment: you mean magic way is ignoring all these features ? I checked it but it spreads out of mobile viewport

Comment: That depends on the browser You Use, but most of them have the option "show as desktop", and then you show it like in desktop, all the page in your mobile screen with extremely small text and image and links, so you have to make always zoom. You can't make it semiresponsive. And sure you can't satisfy your client. Make it realy responsive so he, in the future may be happy, or make it as five years ago, or ten, but users still have to select the option manually in mobile browsers asking for desktop site. You cant fight with progress ;)

Answer (score 0):

Meta will work after reading this https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-multi-screen-site/responsive

Comment: thanks Clark , but I don`t want to make it responsive, I just want to have the structure and layout as same as desktop.